# Is it possible to find who committed what with P4?

Tags: perforce

I would like to know if it is possible to find who committed what with P4.

The best would be getting something like:

```
user committed: com/app/Class.java, com/class/Class2.java etc..
```

Edit:

Ok I can use:

```
p4 changes -m 5 -u user //dev/project/...
```

But this doesn't give me which files have been committed.

Have any idea?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Look through the related questions and you probably can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to identify the last user to modify a the file, you could use something like:

```
p4 filelog -m 1 //dev/project/...
```

This will provide information about the last change to each file, including the name of the user that submitted the change.